# How to display UI for App Center Crashes in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-app-center

We have a UWP app in which we send crash reports using the App Center Crashes api.
In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/uwp#customize-your-usage-of-app-center-crashes) there is a section about displaying UI to the user that a crash report is being submitted, has sent or has failed.

We have been unable to call our own custom UI.

Is there an example on how to call custom UI?

```
 Crashes.SendingErrorReport += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Your code, e.g. to present a custom UI.
        };
```

Comment: `SendingErrorDialog` - could you show us the code? UWP is designed to work with the resictions of the average Mobile App Systems, so limits on how and when you can display a UI should apply. | On a phone, you should only be able to display a UI while the up is in the foreground. Plus maybe having a Notification about something having happened so people look atthe app. UWP on a PC still has to contest with related design decisions.

Comment: @Christopher, Thanks for you help. I've added the ContentDialog code with some sample Xaml.  There is a closing tag for the ContentDialog, for some reason it didn't display above even though it is included in the editor.

Comment: The last closing tag was not properly intended, so it was mistaken for a closing HTML tag or the like. | Unfortunately my practical UWP limit is limited (only here due to C# tag). But with that information someone with real UWP experience can help you.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any `OnProgress`-type of callbacks, so the only option is using 3 events we have:
`SendingErrorReport`, `SentErrorReport` and `FailedToSendErrorReport`.

There is no snippets of usage in UWP demo\puppet apps I can show, but you can have a look at [WPF code](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/blob/ce64aa5826bc0b970f4d3c7d4a6dc0ed41b68639/Apps/Contoso.WPF.Demo/App.xaml.cs#L37-L39) for example, callback signatures are the same.

Basically what you described in original post is correct. I think that something like MessageDialog (documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog)) is what you are looking for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The WPF example above is synchronous. UWP ContentDialog and MessageDialog both ShowAsync. In the context of a crashing app, can you substitute opening a page synchronously with opening a UWP dialog asynchronously? Has anyone actually successfully handled Crashes.SendingErrorReport in UWP? ... anyone at Microsoft perhaps ... No?

Comment: Those events only trigger on the next launch, so it's not quite context of a crashing app, if that's what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm - I was just trying the same issue on UWP - it does NOT work. Will see how I can submit an issue to Appcenter (apparently i don't have enough reputation to add it as a comment).